# Generic type convertion

Tags: generics, types, casting, type-conversion, crystal-lang

I am trying to create a method which gets input from the user and converts that to a specified type. Is there a way to do this without rewriting for each type.

Something like this:

```
struct Input(InputType)
    def self.get_from_stdin(msg_fail : String = "Error! Wrong type, please reenter: ")
        input = gets
        begin
            input = input.to_s.to(InputType)
        rescue
            puts msg_fail
            input = Input(InputType).get_from_stdin
        end
        input
    end
end

age = Input(Int32).get_from_stdin("Age must be a number, please reenter: ")
```

Basically, I want to achieve something akin to this:

```
foo = foo.to(MyType)
```

I imagine this would be difficult to do without macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of messing with generics or macros I would look into ways to reduce boilerplate. That is extract common code into a yielding method and then write specific methods for each case you want to handle on top of that.

```
def prompt_user(prompt)
  print prompt
  print ' '
  loop do
    input = gets
    if input && !input.strip.empty?
      break yield input
    else
      print "Please enter a value: "
    end
  rescue
    print "Wrong type, please reenter: "
  end
end

def prompt_int32(prompt)
  prompt_user(prompt, &.to_i32)
end

def prompt_my_thing(prompt)
  prompt_user(prompt) {|value| MyThing.parse value }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you *really* want to do? What is the exact case you're working on? As you hinted already, of course you can't take an arbitrary string and convert that to any other object, as that would be seriously unsafe/unsound. But if we know your use case we can give some better advice.

Comment: I essentially want to write one (or a couple of) methods which would work for getting all types of user input and converting those into specified types, without writing more methods for getting each type of user input. Jonne Haß's solution I think is an acceptable one since I can write prompt_user("INT PLEASE: ", &.to_i32) for ints and easily adapt to other types. And I am well aware what that could fail, that's why I put a rescue there.